# AS3 Error 1046 - Objects not being found during compile

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors

So when I run my program I get Compiler Errors:

> /Volumes/USB30FD/FlappySharkGame.as, Line 4, Column 2 1046: Type was
>   not found or was not a compile-time constant: `shark`.
>
> /Volumes/USB30FD/FlappySharkGame.as, Line 12, Column 21   1046: Type was
>   not found or was not a compile-time constant: `FlappyShark`.

This is Line 4 of my code, a comment.

```
//allows us to use prewritten code
```

If I delete the comment so that there is nothing on Line 4, run the program - I still get the same above compiler error for Line 4:

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, even though there is nothing written on the particular line?

This is for an introductory course in programming and apps development.  I am completely new to programming, so this all looks like a foreign language to me.

Please help. And Thank you.

Comment: Maybe provide some code to better understand your problem. Also what has that to do with C++?

Comment: Use the [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42109156/edit) button (under those two tags) to add some code. Show us lines **1 up to 10**... This way might be easier to understand your issue. Did you use code like `var something = new shark()`? Does `shark` even exist anywhere in your program so that the compiler understands what you mean?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the input.  The problem is fixed, I added my answer/solution.  Xander - Not sure what it has to do with C++, that tag was automatically there when I was adding tags.

Answer (score 0):

so the fix was pretty easy...

There was nothing wrong with my code.  I showed my professor - the code checked out, everything was properly named, there were no syntax or spelling errors, etc.

She went into my library on the ".fla file" in Adobe Animate CC and selected the latest movie file I had made/converted.  She right clicked it, then clicked on its properties, and hit OK.

She saved it and ran the program and it worked perfectly.

She said, "Sometimes you have to do it again for it to work."